# Using a frozen constant as a hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, constants

I built a small API that makes a few calls that have similar payloads, so I have a base payload that I merge in the call-specific elements, like so:

```
def foo_call
  base_payload.merge({"request.id" => request_id})
end

def biz_call
  base_payload.merge({"request.id" => some_other_thing})
end

def base_payload
  {
    bar: bar,
    baz: baz,
    "request.id" => default_id
  }
end
```

My coworker suggested that I make `"request.id"` a frozen constant, arguing that making it a constant means we can freeze it means we wont be allocating a new string object on each call, saving a bit of memory. That would look like this:

```
REQUESTID = "request.id".freeze

def foo_call
  base_payload.merge({REQUESTID => request_id})
end

def biz_call
  base_payload.merge({REQUESTID => some_other_thing})
end

def base_payload
  {
    bar: bar,
    baz: baz,
    REQUESTID => default_id
  }
end
```

I'm a little apprehensive, but I can't quite pin down any reason why not to do this (other than my latent resistance at having a new commit `:>`). I feel it might cause weirdness to have the same *object* be the key in multiple hashes -- that merging in an object `"request.id"` might not overwrite the original string from the base_payload -- or that we won't actually see any memory saved since the hash would have to clone the string for its hash key anyway, but I'm not really sure.

Am I just being overly paranoid/resistant?

Comment: Why use a string at all? You can say `:'request.id' => ...` or, depending on your Ruby version, `'request.id': ...`. Or use all strings, pretty much anything to avoid mixing hashrockets and the JavaScript style in one Hash literal :)

Comment: Freezing will help, but it has nothing to do with referring to it as a constant.

Comment: Saving a less than 100 bytes is not worth it to think about. The biggest benefit I see in using a (frozen) constant instead of a simple string is that it makes refactoring easier and less error-prone.